# Google Tag manager unable to block tracking in admin

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a PageView tracking tag on all pages on my site.
Its triggered on GTM.dom

I am trying to block the tag from firing on /admin pages however when I set up a blocking tag, then it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas why?

Here is the configuration: 
[image: Tag Configuration]
Admin trigger:
[image: Admin Trigger]
Gtm Dom
[image: gtm.dom]

I have taken the site down while I am testing, so would be useful to have it working.

Comment: Did you published your changes in GTM? Dont you have HTTPS on Admin section? What about www. prefix?

Comment: Yes Changes were pubilshed. I have tried using HTTP/ HTTTPs and we don't use www. anwhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use filter instead of exception

[image]